# Terraform AWS, S3 replication configuration - `depends_on` Bucket versioning configuration from another module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have an S3 bucket that I want to replicate objects from to another bucket. The S3 bucket has versioning enabled, as required by S3 replication.

Several components (modules) of my infrastructure work on that bucket, each with their own key prefix. I want the complete configuration of these components separated from each other (separation of concerns), into distinct terraform modules, including the corresponding replication configuration for the component's individual key prefixes. That is, I'll end up with a list of replication configs, each entry belonging to one and only one of the components.

Generally, this is working so far. The problem is that (I think) I need a `depends_on` entry in all of the replication configurations pointing to the `aws_s3_bucket_versioning` resource of the source bucket. That configuration lies in another module, the one that configures the bucket itself. There is no data source for `aws_s3_bucket_versioning` available that I might use.

So, the question is probably twofold...

- how would I go on about this?
- is my concept sound? Does this even make sense, to have individual replication configurations for each component, apart from the actual bucket configuration?

Comment: Can you please provide TF code demonstrating your issue?

Comment: It's company owned and I'm prohibited to provide the actual code. I can try and come up with MWE...

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you would like to replicate from one source bucket to multiple destination buckets.

perhaps something like such may resolve your issue:

```
locals {
  replication_buckets = toset(["one", "two", "three"])
}


#### SOURCE BUCKET
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "main" {
  bucket = "my-main-bucket"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "main" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.main.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "main" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.main.id

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.main]

  role = aws_iam_role.some_replication_role.arn

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = local.replication_buckets
    content {
      id = each.key

      filter {
        prefix = each.key #alter this to your liking , you may want a map of objects for this sort of config with prefix, bucket-name etc as properties of the obj
      }

      status = "Enabled"

      destination {
        bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.replication_buckets[each.key].arn
        storage_class = "STANDARD"
      }
    }
  }
}


### destination/replication buckets
# this can be a module with a for_each on the module
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "replication_buckets" {
  for_each = local.replication_buckets
  bucket   = "bucket-${each.key}-12345"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "replication_buckets" {
  for_each = local.replication_buckets
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.replication_buckets[each.key].id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

you would only need one replication configuration as there is one main bucket , the rest of the destination buckets would not need a replication configuration as they are receiving objects from that one bucket.

Hopefully this helps with your depends_on problem